# How to vectorize Mersenne Twister loops over arrays

Tags: vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx2, mersenne-twister

Currently i'm working with an custom implementation of the Mersenne Twister, and i'd like to improve my understanding of vector operations.

I have the following code:

```
#define N 624
#define M 397

 for( k = N -1; k; k-- )
 {
    array[i] = (array[i] ^ ((array[i-1] ^ (array[i-1] >> 30)) * 1566083941UL)) - i;
    array[i] &= 0xffffffffUL;
    ++i;

    if ( i >= N )
    {
        array[0] = array[N-1];
        i = 1;
    }
 }
```

Here i'm working with 32 bit integers only, so as i understand, I could perform 8 times as much operations at the same time, using AVX2 instructions?  How can I do that in practice?

I know how to deal with addition of 2 vectors, but this case seems to be more complicated.  I don't know how to begin.

For a scalar approach i'd work like that, but i'd like to get sure how to perform these actions in my case.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
 {
    C[i] = A[i]*B[i];
 }



for (i = 0; i < 1024; i+=4)
  {
     C[i:i+3] = A[i:i+3]*B[i:i+3];
  }
```

Unfortunately at my university there are no lessons about intrinsics, but i'm quite curious in order to get an improvement.

I'm also doing some thoughts, about how to create the array using vectors? Maybe matrix? (Maybe `_mm256_setr_epi32`)

I hope to get some advice regarding this topic!

Comment: For generic guides about SIMD, SSE/AVX you can check the [SSE tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info). If you have a specific question about a problem, provide a valid [mre]!

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll create an example, containing the loop shown above, in order to have some running code.

Comment: GCC should auto-vectorize that `C[i] = A[i]*B[i];` loop for you, efficiently with SSE4.1 `pmulld` or the AVX2 256-bit version.  (`gcc -O3 -march=native`)

Comment: Thanks, that was just an example of how i'd like to solve this problem. I have edited the code where i'm working on, in order to make it a little bit more simple. I got 2 loops, one inside of another, and i perform a lot of array operations, and logical operations, so i'd like to know, where i could optimize these opterizations, because in case of addition of 2 vectors it's quite easy, but here i got bitwise XOR and shift operations.

Comment: SIMD xor and shift aren't a problem, and with AVX2 neither is integer mul.  The problem is the serial dependency of `array[i]` on `array[i-1]`.  That's kryptonite for SIMD, although SIMD prefix sums are possible.  But unlike a prefix sum, it's unlikely this is decomposable enough to calculate 4 or 8 elements ahead and achieve / create any data parallelism.

Comment: Use [SFMT](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/) (Or a simpler, higher quality PRNG).